# Clear TotalCache cache automatically from code WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several WordPress sites hosted in my server, and some of them have the W3 Total Cache plugin installed. Right now I flush the cache for each site manually, but I want to do it programatically and all together.

I'm trying to write a PHP script that will do this. I was looking at the code used by the "Clean Cache All" option for this plugin in the dashboard, and is this piece here:

```
if ( $modules->plugin_is_enabled() ) {
$menu_items['10010.generic'] = array(
'id' => 'w3tc_flush_all',
'parent' => 'w3tc',
'title' => __( 'Purge All Caches', 'w3-total-cache' ),
'href' => wp_nonce_url( network_admin_url(
'admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard&amp;w3tc_flush_all' ),
'w3tc' ));
```

So I'm guessing there are 2 ways to do what I need:

1- Make a web request, but that would probably require authentication.

2- Instance the class and use the method w3tc_flush_all();

This is what I have thus far:

```
function clean_cache($web)
{
        global $path;
        $path2 = $path.$web["directory"]."/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/";
        if(file_exists($path2)) //Tienen TotalCache instalado
        {
                require_once $path.'w3-total-cache-api.php';
                //if(class_exists("w3-total-cache-api.php"))
                //{
                        $plugin_totalcache = & w3_instance("w3-total-cache-api.php");
                        //if(function_exists('w3tc_dbcache_flush'))
                        $plugin_totalcache->w3tc_fush_all();
                //}

        }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look into using `wp_cron` to do this automatically https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

Comment: in php script?.

Comment: You have a typo:  `w3tc_fush_all` should be `w3tc_flush_all`